# How to use brew opencv3 with C++ on mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, macos, opencv

I installed opencv3 using homebrew using this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/)

But how can I use it with C++ on eclipse/xcode? I went through the opencv documentation for eclipse CDT [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d16/tutorial_linux_eclipse.html). But I dont have a separate opencv folder in /usr/local but rather a single folder /usr/local/cellar/opencv3. How can I use this with C++?

Answer (score 0):

You need to config eclipse/xcode to search for headers in 
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/_version_name_here/includes`
while the libraries are in
`/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/_version_name_here/lib`. 
For eclipse you need to include each library by hand, just as in the opencv document. For xcode, you can add (symlink) the libraries to your projects.